# Strange behavior of PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Good time of the day!

I've been given a task for my masters project to develop mobile application without usage of any frameworks available out there (i mean Symfony/Laravel/Phalcon, etc).

Since i used to work quite alot with Laravel, i've been trying to recreate some of the methods available in Laravel in my own "framework".

However, i encountered very strange problem while working with PDO.
Here is what i am trying to do:

1. I want to create user using `User::create([]);` method of the User model (yes, i sort of recreated the model system).
2. If i'm retrieving data from the database, there is no problem in getting correct data. Even the `User::where('name', 'User Name')->orWhere('name', 'User Name')->first()->toArray()`  chain works fine (query is not "deformed")
3. Upon creation, the SQL query looks just fine (dumped it before execution with `str_replace`)
4. After query is executed, database is populated with data from only one column (last column)

Here is the `create(array $parameters)` method:

```
try {
        $reference = (new static);
        $sqlStatement = sprintf('INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (', $reference->table, implode(', ', $reference->fillable));
        foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
            $reference->$key = $value;
            $sqlStatement .= ':' . $key . ', ';
        }
        $sqlStatement = rtrim($sqlStatement, ', ') . ')';
        $statement = $reference->connection->prepare($sqlStatement);
        foreach ($parameters as $key => $value)
            $statement->bindParam(':' . $key, $value);
        $statement->execute();
        return $reference;
    } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
        dd($exception);
    }
```

I am seriously have no idea what is wrong here, since the PHP and SQL parts look just fine.
Any help or ideas are really appreciated!

Comment: Your foreach lacks curly braces. Also `->bindValue` unless it's an output parameter.

Comment: Thank you. I guess i need to sleep more. Almost 7am and i've been working on it for past 15 hours. Thanks again!

Comment: Keep in mind Laravel does a lot of things to keep your parameters secure. It's imperative that you properly escape any and all values you put in here: table names also need to be escaped with backticks or they will cause problems: A table or column named "order" will crash this code. I hope this is an academic exercise because using your own framework in production code is how you quickly rediscover how painful it is to write one that's feature complete. If someone wants code "without frameworks" that's a job you probably want to pass on, the liability is too high.

Comment: @tadman it is an academic exercise. We are still forced to use mysqli (PDO is a "next-level" dont use it). I'm playing with "PHP" for about 7-8 years now, but if you are told "not to use any frameworks, write code by yourself", you cant argue.

Comment: @IvanZhivolupov If that's too space-age that's concerning. PHP 5.1 introduced PDO...in 2005.